# Аналог CASE WHEN при работе с XML в MS SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server, dom

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь аналог CASE WHEN при работе с XML ?
Допустим, мне нужно в зависимости от значения узла XML делать разные вставки в XML.

Comment: Эм.. Xml же превращается в таблицу какой-то командой. В чём именно проблема?

Comment: Есть узел, допустим, flag. В зависимости от его содержания удаляются определенным дочерние узлы. Можно ли в xml.modify('delete ') сделать какое-нибудь ветвление?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В XQuery можно использовать традиционный условный оператор [if-then-else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190171%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

```
declare @foo table  ( bar xml )

insert @foo values('
<root>
    <flag>1</flag>
    <a>a</a>
    <b>b</b>
</root>')

select * from @foo

update @foo
set bar.modify('delete if (data(//flag) = "1") then (//a) else (//b)')

select * from @foo
```

---

Для изменения xml, приведенного в комментарии, нужно использовать [цикл](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190945%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
update @foo
set bar.modify('
    delete
        for $row in /root/TableRow
            return if ($row/flag = 1) then $row/a else $row/b
')
```

Проходим в цикле по всем узлам `TableRow`, и в зависимости от значения узла `flag` возвращаем узел `a` или `b`, который и будет удалён.

Comment: А вот в таком XML как сделать, что бы в первом случае удалялся узел a, а во втором узел b ?<root>
 <TableRow>
 <flag>1</flag>
 <a>a</a>
 <b>b</b>
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
 <flag>2</flag>
 <a>a</a>
 <b>b</b>
 </TableRow>
</root>
Altova XmlSpy выводит мне в обоих случаях a.

Comment: @iluxa1810 - Не помещайте код в комментарии. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него код и другую дополнительную информацию. А в комментарии укажите: "Обновил вопрос".  PS: Обновил ответ.

Comment: А можно ли так же через такой же цикл выполнять replace value of ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 - Насколько я знаю, нет, нельзя. Дело в том, что `replace value of` обрабатывает только один узел за раз. Если очень нужен ответ, создавайте новую тему. Может кто-то другой подскажет, а в комментариях ваш вопрос кроме меня (и, может быть, модераторов) вряд ли заметят.